# Finding variance of grouped data

Tags: r

I'm new to R and stats and am doing an assignment question where I have to calculate the variance of grouped data. I'm getting a negative number for some reason and I have no idea why. Any help would be great!

Formula:

[image: formula]

m = midpoints, f = frequency, n = number of elements

```
midpoints = c(2.5, 7.5, 12.5, 17.5, 22.5, 27.5, 32.5, 37.5)
freq = c(7, 26, 59, 71, 62, 39, 22, 14)
m = (sum(midpoints * freq))/8

mf_square = sum((midpoints ** 2) * freq)
mf = sum(midpoints * freq)

var = (mf_square - ((mf ** 2)/8))/7
```

Output of var is -602139.29

Comment: Could you include whatever formulas you're referrencing in setting this up?

Comment: @camille https://gyazo.com/8c8bba6e44ac359c35be7cd3068a4c18

Comment: m = midpoint, f = frequency, n = number of elements

Comment: I should have been more specific. Can you add that to the question? You probably don't have access to putting an image inline yet, but you can add it to the post and someone else will probably put it inline for you

Comment: n is supposed to be the total number of observations, which is the sum of frequencies. Right now you're using the number of classes. I'm voting to have this moved to [stats.se] because your code is fine, the issue is with interpreting the formula